# How do I export VLC media library to file?

Tags: vlc-media-player, web, export, media, libraries

I can create folders and organize some http rtsp streams in media library but I can not export it to a file to be able to backup and transfer to another comp. or user.

Do you have any idea how can I save media library with its organisation to a file ?

Answer (score 3):

**How To Transfer/Copy the VLC Player Media Library from an Old Computer to a New Machine**

This is very easy to do -

The Media Library file will appear in the VLC media player folder along with the application and will be named "**ml.xspf**".

So, locate the **ml.xspf** file inside the VLC Player folder on your computer.

On my Windows 7 machine it is located in the folder located at:

C:\Users\ *profile name*\AppData\Roaming\vlc

(You can also use your computers search function to find the location of the file on your machine).

Once you're satisfied you have the right file, simply copy it to a safe location until you're ready to install it in your VLC Player on your new machine.

Then, when you're ready to install it on the new machine, copy it to the same location on the new computer, after renaming the existing ml.xspf file to something like "ml.xspf_OLD" or simply replacing any existing ml.xspf file, if prompted.

When you open VLC Player on the new machine, your Media Library will be populated with the exact same directory structure as existed on the VLC Player on your old machine... ;-)

Enjoy...!

Comment: @Mickey Cashen noted this works in Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and Glenn answered it.  But I wonder why the OP didn't mark it as answered.  The other answer should be inverted, I think, in that ...

1. Select, copy, paste your media library folder to playlist folder.
2. Then use VLC's ctrl-Y save playlist to file option.
3. Done. (But my quick test shows that your Media Library's folder structure gets flattened when you copy to the Playlist.)

This might help some people who don't feel comfortable finding and copying program files and would rather use the interface.  Also for some it may be hard to remember the file name to search for after a long time of not using it.

Comment: I did not because I am in linux and I want an orthodox way via vlc binary or guil to do this instead of copying its internal file I was searching another way. Nevertheless I will mark if another safe and sound way to do this. If there is none, it must take place in vlc development branch because saving a playlist as organized seems crucial to me.

Answer (score -1):

In the save menu you should see 'save playlist to file'. If not add those to you media library and use that option on the media library itself.

Comment: It doesnt work. I try to save main folder and there are many subfolders in it. It saves an empty xspf file.