# Backing up the VLC Media Library

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player

I am using VLC on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I wanted to save the media library to a file and import it to other players I use. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1160615/how-do-i-export-vlc-media-library-to-file/1206514) is the only relevant result I found. I searched my entire file system with catfish for ml.xspf but it returned 0 results. Is there another way to export the media library?